# Upstart : start service after non-upstart process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, process, upstart

On Ubuntu 10.04, I need to start my service with upstart, but only when mysql is up and running.

The problem is that mysql itself is not handled by upstart, so I can't use the "start on" feature.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) make mysql inform Upstart that it has started by emitting an event

`initctl emit mysql-started`" or similar.

This could be handled by adding the `initctl` invocation to `/etc/init.d/mysql`.

2) Disable mysql from the normal SysV runlevels and create a wrapper Upstart job that
  starts it (not this doesn't handle stopping - just an example):

```
cat >>/etc/init/mysql-sysv.conf<<EOT
  # wait for SysV job to finish
  start on stopped rc
  exec /etc/init.d/mysql start
EOT
```

Then, have your job "`start on started mysql-sysv`".

The problem here is that you'll run into trouble if someone (or some system tool automatically) re-adds the `/etc/rc?.d` links to the original `/etc/init.d/mysql` service script. Also, you may find that mysql isn't actually ready until some time *after* it's main pid has started. Databases are problematic as they might take some time to come "online" even after they have started (transction log replay, etc).

3) Create an upstart job ("waiter") that does "start on stopped rc" (ie start when all the SysV jobs have claimed to have finished) and then polls waiting for mysql to become ready, then exits. Have your job "start on stopped waiter".

4) Convert mysql to an Upstart job (the best option). There's a starting point for an upstart mysql configuration up here: https://github.com/devo-ps/init-scripts/tree/master/mysql/ubuntu

Comment: After looking around, this answer sums up all the options I have. Also thank you for pointing out the gap between "started mysql" and the time when mysql is actually available. Let's see if #4 was already tried somewhere.

Comment: Option 3 requires "start on started waiter". Not on stopped.

Comment: option 1 fits our model well!  We first download all upstart scripts from a config server via python script which runs `os.system('/sbin/initctl emit consul-finished')`, then start other services by `start on consul-finished`

Comment: Thanks for that, my friend! Basically I ended up having to sed-replace `initctl emit cloud-init-finished` a sysv service to be able to hook up

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting your upstart job after *all* non-upstart jobs are finished:

> `start on started rc`

`/etc/init/rc.conf` is the thing that starts non-upstart jobs from within upstart.

Props: https://serverfault.com/a/533481

Answer (score -1):

How about using

```
pre-start exec /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

inside your upstart job !

Comment: ...that will not magically start the **upstart** job when mysql starts.

Comment: yeah that is not what you asked!!! you asked for other way round . At least that is how i understood

Comment: My upstart job is supposed to monitor mysql and send notifications if it's down. I feel a bit unconfortable launching mysql via the monitoring job

Comment: I don't think is entirely wrong. I do something like this: 
pre-start script
    if ! /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server status &>/dev/null; then
        /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
    fi
end script